# Empirical quantile mapping

Tags: meteorology, climate-models, statistics, r

I'm not sure if this is the right section to post this, but since it's about weather and statistics I am posting it here first.

I tried using R's qmap package to do a simple experiment using this function below for observed and modeled data.

```
fitQmap(obs,mod,method=c("PTF","DIST","RQUANT","QUANT","SSPLIN"),...)
doQmap(x, fobj, ...)
```

The figure below shows the PDF (obs. and mod.) uncorrected and corrected.

How would you exactly interpret the results?

I noticed that observed values had events of higher wind speeds and the the model did not. What physical property can suggest such thing?

Also, since the corrected modeled one almost **exactly** matches the observed one, does this mean there is overfitting? How would I know if it weren't overfitted to the model?

Thanks for any help or suggestion!

[image]